# Why is this the truth table for AND,OR with NULL?

Tags: sql, null, boolean, logic

In the following truth table for `AND` and `OR` using a `NULL` value (taken from a MySQL query):

[image]

I am guessing that `NULL AND NULL`|`NULL OR NULL` will never short-circuit so return the final `NULL`.

But how do the other 3VL work? For example, why wouldn't `FALSE OR NULL` return `FALSE`? Why wouldn't `FALSE AND NULL` return `NULL`?

The best resource I could find here is: https://modern-sql.com/concept/three-valued-logic

---

By the way, to test in SQL you can do:

```
select 'AND' op, true and null , false and null, null and null 
union all
select 'OR', true or null, false or null, null or null
```

Comment: Null combined with anything is null. Null is not true, but it's not false either.

Comment: @Bohemian what do you mean by "combined" ? `NULL OR TRUE` is not `NULL` but `TRUE`.

Comment: @Bohemian I suppose you mean as an operand to any operator except for `AND`,`OR`,`IS [NOT] NULL`?

Comment: Generally, if there's a null involved, the result is null, even if it doesn't make sense. For example `1 in (1,2,3,null)` is not `true`

Comment: @Bohemian what rdbms does that? I tried it in mysql, postgres, and sqlserver and they all return `t` for `select 1 in (1,2,3,null)` -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/334598

Comment: Oops. I meant when the value is null: `null not in (1,2,3)` returns `null`, which is *not* true (it's not false either), but many would expect it to return `true`, so they get unexpected results when coding `select ... where table.column not in (1,2,3)` expecting the rows with null in that column to be returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL Standard defines null as a *missing value*. It does exist, but it's just missing, so it's not in the data [yet].

Furthermore, the SQL Standard defines three logical values:

- True
- False
- Unknown

The last one is represented by a null.

Then, `false OR null` can evaluate to false or true, depending if the missing value in the right side ends up being false or true respectively. Therefore the result is `Unknown` (null).

On the other hand, `false AND null` can only evaluate to false. It doesn't matter if the missing value in the right side evaluates to false or true. In both cases the result of the expression would be false.

Comment: Great answer thank you, and love your work on [Check the Plan](https://checktheplan.com/) !

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to conceptualize it. Imagine that the `NULL` value, in the context of a logical SQL expression, may evaluate to either `TRUE` or `FALSE` since it is an indeterminate value. Now, let's substitute in **both** `TRUE` and `FALSE` where there may be a `NULL` value -- if it gives a single logical value, then we know it will be that, if it gives both, then it is still indeterminate and thus we can set it to `NULL`. Let's try it out:

1. `NULL AND NULL` --> `TRUE AND TRUE` (TRUE), `FALSE AND FALSE` (FALSE) --> `NULL`
2. `NULL OR NULL` --> `TRUE OR TRUE` (TRUE), `FALSE OR FALSE` (FALSE) --> `NULL`
3. `NULL AND TRUE` --> `TRUE AND TRUE` (TRUE), `FALSE AND TRUE` (FALSE) --> `NULL`
4. `NULL OR TRUE` --> `FALSE OR TRUE` (TRUE), `TRUE OR TRUE` (TRUE) --> `TRUE`
5. `NULL AND FALSE` --> `FALSE AND FALSE` (FALSE), `TRUE AND FALSE` (FALSE) --> `FALSE`
6. `NULL OR FALSE` --> `FALSE OR FALSE` (FALSE), `TRUE OR FALSE` (TRUE) --> `NULL`

So there, by seeing if the resultant value can be predicted or not we can see whether the result is a single logical value or the indeterminate `NULL`.